# Корректный код, чтобы функция включалась при 1024px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если какой либо метод, чтобы как только пользователь доходит до 1024px, функция начинала свою работу? Например, `$(window).on('resizeEnd', function(){}` заработает?

Comment: А зачем? Что делает эта функция? Может это нужно делать в CSS?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Нет, он будет высчитывать расстояние от родителя до блока и давать ему расстояние от верха. Сумеешь так на css?)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а скрипты, которые нужно вызывать только при определённом размере окна браузера устройства, вы тоже через `css` будете?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов надо смотреть конкретную вёрстку. Может и сумею

Comment: @MasterAlex поэтому я и спросил что делает этот скрипт. Слишком часто вместо пары строк на css начинают городить страшные непонятные и тупящие скрипты

Comment: @AlexeyTen я уверен, что тут каскадные таблицы бессильны)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так заработает:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var started = false;

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1023 && !start) {             
        // Код, который нужно исполнить

        started = true;
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {

        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1023 && !start) {
          // Код, который нужно исполнить

          started = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Только учитывайте один момент, что если расширять экран дальше, код будет выполняться снова и снова и если это не нужно, то поможет переменная `started`.

**UPD.** Дополнил функцию. Теперь она может срабатывать до ресайза при выполнении условий. Если исполняемого кода немало, то можно повторяющиеся фрагменты вынести в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Спасибо!Мне, правда, нужно наоборот - когда меньше чем, но это не важно.Код будет работать корректно и в Хроме, и Мозилле?

Comment: во всех браузерах будет работать

Comment: Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Извини, немного не такая работа. Пользователь не будет менять разрешение вручную, а функция срабатывает если я вручную сменю разрешение экрана.Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, то есть нужно чтобы функция срабатывала ещё и сразу, при нужном разрешении?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, обновил ответ, такое поведение нужно?

Comment: Да, супер. Спасибо

Comment: А как можно избежать дублирования исполняемого кода?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, я написал в ответе об этом в самом конце, делаете функцию с нужным кодом `function runCode() { // код }` и добавляете эту функцию в оба условия `runCode();`