# JavaScript: как повторно выполнить скрипт из внешнего файла?

Tags: javascript, html, адаптивная-верстка

Вопрос новичка: как вызвать выполнение следующего скрипта адаптивной вёрстки при изменении ширины страницы, если скрипт находится во внешнем файле (ссылка на него добавлена в `<head>` и он единыжды выполняется при формировании страницы)?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vp_width = $(window).width();
    if (vp_width >= 240 && vp_width <= 320){

  ...
    } 
});
```

Я уже узнал, что следует добавить тегу `<body>` атрибут со значением `onResize`, осталось только разобраться со значением этого атрибута. Была бы эта функция с именем, её не составило бы труда вызвать, но ведь тут просто конструкция с функцей без имени.

Comment: посмотрите ответ в этом вопросе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529120

Comment: Благодарю Вас, думаю это то, что надо. Но можно ли избежать повтора кода в двух функциях?

Comment: делаете функцию с нужным кодом `function runCode() { // код }` и добавляете вызов этой функции везде где нужно `runCode();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью метода `bind`:

```js
function body_resize() {
    var vp_width = $(window).width();

    if (vp_width >= 240 && vp_width <= 320){
      alert("body has width >= 240 and <= 320");
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  body_resize();
});

$(window).bind("resize", function() {
  body_resize();
  alert("body has resize");
});
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  test
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Этот пример нельзя протестировать на этом сайте, попробуйте [тут](http://xhtml.ru/instr/html_editor/)