# Адаптивная вёрстка с помощью JS: с чего начать

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка

Этот вопрос связан с моим другим вопросом - [Javascript: как повторно выполнить скрипт из внешнего файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538416/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/538510#538510) Речь шла о создании скрипта адаптивной вёрстки, который должен был выполняться при каждом изменении ширины окна. То решение меня не устроило тем, что скрипт не только срабатывает многократно до того, как при изменении размера окна кнопка мыши отпущена, но и затем окно возвращалось в исходное положение.

Я бы хотел начать с максимально простого скрипта, чтобы потом его модифицировать. Дополните, пожалуйста, нижеследующий скрипт *минимальным* количеством кода так, чтобы он срабатывал при каждом изменении длины окна, но только после того, как кнопка мыши отпущена.

```
function body_resize() {
    var vp_width = $(window).width();

    if (vp_width >= 240 && vp_width <= 320){
        alert ("Текущая ширина окна от 240 до 320 px")   
    }

    if (vp_width >= 320){
        alert ("Текущая ширина окна более 320 px")
    }
}
```

И ещё: есть ли какие-нибудь средства в JS наподобие счётчика количества раз выполнения скрипта? Долго объяснять, зачем это нужно, вкратце скажу, что это поможет упростить скрипт. Хочу сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
// i - количество завершённых выполнений скрипта
if (i=1) alert("Скрипт выполняется впервые");
else alert("Скрипт выполняется"+i+"-ый раз");
```

Comment: >он срабатывал при каждом изменении длины окна, но только после того, как кнопка мыши отпущена.

Вы должны понимать, что есть и другие способы изменить размер окна, которые не зависят от мышки

Comment: Всё верно Вы говорите, но моя задача - избежать того, чтобы при изменении ширины окна мышью скрипт каждый раз выполнялся, иначе всё содержимое сайта будет в прямом смысле прыгать и скакать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac  тут есть ответ на ваш вопрос. В смысле как сделать выполнение только по завершению ресайза. А по количеству выполнений, сделайте себе глобальный счетчик и увеличивайте каждый при вызове этой функции.